# Why does my computer detect the USB driver for Bluetooth 5.3 but cannot connect and use Bluetooth?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

unable to use Bluetooth despite recognizing USB driver Bluetooth 5.3 in Ubuntu 23.04"

"I have Ubuntu 23.04 installed on my computer and I'm having trouble using Bluetooth. Here are the steps I've taken:
I have a USB driver for Bluetooth 5.3, which I have successfully mounted.
When I run the lsusb command, I can see that Ubuntu recognizes the USB driver.
However, I am unable to connect and use Bluetooth functionality.
Interestingly, when I boot into Windows on the same machine, Bluetooth works fine, so I suspect there might be some missing software or package in Ubuntu.

I would greatly appreciate any help in identifying what I need to install or configure in order to use Bluetooth properly on Ubuntu 23.04. Thank you in advance for your assistance!"

Comment: it looks like you took a wrong turn on the internet. [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is the better place for your question. In any case, the corresponding excerpt on the boot log is also necessary. Something like `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

Comment: ah yes, thank you, i saw the message error with that command

Comment: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
HCI device and connection manager initialized
: HCI socket layer initialized
: L2CAP socket layer initialized
: SCO socket layer initialized
: hci0: HCI Read Default Erroneous Data Reporting command is advertised, but not supported.
: hci0: Opcode 0x204b failed: -56
: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
: BNEP socket layer initialized
: hci0: HCI Read Default Erroneous Data Reporting command is advertised, but not supported.
: hci0: Opcode 0x204b failed: -56